# Fetch api not able to get data with get method in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

After upgrading `react-native` from 0.64.0 to 0.68.2, I started facing the issue with GET api calling. Earlier it was working fine with `axios`, after upgrade neither `axios` working nor `fetch`. I tried `fetch` just to check if it works or not but that isn't working. Here is code sample with `fetch`, as I seen on several tutorial online.

```js
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const requestParams = {
      userId: authReducer.userId,
      token: authReducer.userToken,
      limit: 20
    };
    console.log('start');
    let response = await fetch('https://websiteurl.com/getuserbyid/4', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${requestParams.token}`
      }
    });
    console.log('end');
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    console.log(responseJson);
    setIsLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);       
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  getUser();
}, []);
```

In above code

> console.log('start');

prints the `"start"` in console but after it doesn't fetch the record. It doesn't execute the catch statement in case of any network error or anything. Can anyone help in this?

Comment: Maybe the RAM format ? try setting inlineRequires: false, in metro.config.js. Readmore: https://reactnative.dev/docs/ram-bundles-inline-requires#enable-the-ram-format

Comment: Did you find the related response? I have this problem too.